# 'abyss-pe' troubleshooting for genome assembly

Tags: linux, makefile, bioinformatics, dna-sequence, genome

I'm trying to create contigs using the ABySS genome assembler from raw fastq reads. I'm working in my university's Linux server via SSH.

The command I have used is:

```
 abyss-pe name=SRR530529_1 k=27 in= /home/bilalm/H_glaber_quality_filtering/AfterQC/good_reads/SRR530529.good.fq
```

The output from the terminal:

```
make: Nothing to be done for '/home/bilalm/H_glaber_quality_filtering_AfterQC_good_reads/SRR530529.good.fq'.
```

What am I doing wrong? Have I missed out commands? Is it a permissions issue?

Comment: Are you sure there's supposed to be a space between `in=` and the filename?  That makes it 2 separate arguments, unlike the `k=27`.  Apparently abyss-pe uses `make` under the hood for something, but IDK what because I've never heard of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a space in the argument list splitting one argument into two. Change it into this:

```
abyss-pe name=SRR530529_1 k=27 in=/home/bilalm/H_glaber_quality_filtering/AfterQC/good_reads/SRR530529.good.fq
#---------------------------------^ Notice how the space has been removed
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! its 'Reading' the file now.